# Combining training, validation and test datasets

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

Is it possible to train a model based on training and validation data sets.Basically end up combining both of them to create a new model. And from that combined model use it to classify all of the data in the test dataset.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is usually done. Assuming that you know how to transfer hyperparameters, as you usually fit model on train data, select hyperparameters based on the score on the valid one. Thus when you combine train + valid you get significantly bigger dataset, thus "optimal hyperparameters" might be completely different from the ones you selected before. So in general - yes, this is exactly what is usually done, but it might be more tricky than you expect (especially if your method is highly stochastic, non deterministic, etc.).